# Rails 4 scope with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I have a product which is to be featured between a date range. So I have

```
is_active :boolean
featured  :boolean
featured_start_date :date
featured_end_date   :date
```

now I need to write a scope which should return to me all the featured products for today's date. I am not sure how I can pass the conditional date when writing the scope please assist. What I have right now is:

```
scope :featured, -> { where(is_active: true, featured: true, ) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the current date is contained in the featured date range. ActiveRecord has no direct solution to this. You have some options though:

Using SQL fragments

```
scope :featured, -> {
  where(is_active: true, featured: true)
  .where('featured_start_date <= ?', Date.today)
  .where('featured_end_date >= ?', Date.today)
}
```

Using ARel

```
scope :featured, -> {
  where(is_active: true, featured: true)
  .where(Product.arel_table[:featured_start_date].lteq Date.today)
  .where(Product.arel_table[:featured_end_date].gteq Date.today)
}
```

There are more possibilities but these should work just fine.